# PyQGIS: How to find out if point is before, beneath or after a line geometry

Tags: pyqgis, topology

I have got a line dataset and a point dataset and I wrote a function that snaps every point onto the closest line. My data look like that:
[image]
However, the function I use ([QgsGeometry.nearestPoint()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a412e55ba03454baa52ec3dc49901baaa)) also snaps points before and after the line; in the image above e.g. the points to the lower left and to the upper right.

Also related functions (I tried i.A. `QgsGeometry.closestSegmentWithcontext()` and `QgsLineString.closestSegment()`) show the same behaviour. So how can I check in PyQGIS whether a point geometry is "before", "along" or "after" a line geometry, in order to exclude them from my snapping routine?

Comment: Is there an maximum distance that a point can be away from the line? Presumably you have other points and other lines in your layers?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to snap points that are more than a certain distance away from the line, but that's a parameter that might depend on the particular data I work with. Sometimes, 10m would be a reasonable threshold, sometimes rather 50m.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Buffer (native), or v.buffer in the GRASS tools, then you can create a buffer on the lines, with no end caps:

**Buffer (native)**

[image]

**v.buffer (GRASS)**

[image]

This will give you a region that you can then use to intersect your points, to control the ones that get snapped vs the ones that don't:

[image]

This process should be fairly easy to translate to use in your PyQGIS function.

Comment: Nice idea! The flat end-cap option is also available in the native QGIS Buffer tool.

Comment: @Matt - thanks, good point, I hadn't noticed what the "End cap style" options were for. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could use QgsGeometry.boundingBox() to determine if the point is inside of the boundingBox of your line

```
lyr_line = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("LINE")[0]
lyr_points = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("POINTS")[0]

snapped_points = []

for line in lyr_line.getFeatures():
    for point in lyr_points.getFeatures():
        if point.id() in snapped_points:
            #To prevent snapping the same point after being snapped once
            continue
        if point.geometry().intersects(line.geometry().boundingBox()):
            snapped_points.append(point.id())

#for debug purposes 
lyr_points.selectByIds(snapped_points)
```

Dataset of points and a single line, before running the code
[image]

Representation of the boundingBox()
[image]

Points inside of the boundingBox selected, after running the code
[image]

As it is, the code does not guarantee that the point will snap to the closest line. Since one point could be in the boundingBox of multiple lines, example:
[image]

Those two points are in boundingBox of both lines.

Maybe you should look into QgsSpatialIndex.nearestNeighbor() and see if it provides an adequate solution to find the closest line to each point, and then see if the point intersects the boundingBox of closest line

Comment: Bounding box is an Interesting idea, but it has some drawbacks: As you can see in your 2nd screenshot, the bounding box excludes also points that are "beneath" the line, but close to the end of the line. Points at the same lateral distance, but longitudinally closer to the middle of the line, would be inside the BB.

Comment: But deriving from that, I start thinking of using a buffer around the line. By that, the lateral distance to include/exclude points would be always the same along the whole line. And I already saw that I can control the shape of the buffer at the line end (https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#aadaa55e0ec87eb390b18e86ce6a2e8ae)
A bit much of analysis for a simple problem, but I think it would work.